# Storing Elements of a Matrix

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to store elements of the matirces UE and RE computed at the end of the following R-code NBoot=1000 times. So that I may recall them later like UE[i] and RE[i] times for i=1 to 1000. I have tried to solve by constructing an outer loop, but some what I am unable to store the values. Please suggest me some way out.
Here is the sample code that I am implementing:

```
set.seed(20531)
################ Setting up various quantities ################
NBoot=1000    
alpha=0.05
    c=0.5
    q=4
    ni=100
    n=q*ni;n
    ################ Setting Population Means and Standard Deviations ################
    mu0=c(5,5,5,5)
    sigma=c(1,1.5,2,2.5)
    ################ Creating Empty Matrix ################
    Dat=matrix(data=NA,nrow=ni,ncol=q)
    ################ Setting Up Loops ################
    for(j in 1:q){
       for(i in 1:ni){
          Dat[i,j]=rnorm(1,mu0[j],sigma[j])
       }
    }
    ################ Giving Names to Rows and Columns of DATA Matrix ################
    dimnames(Dat) <- list(rownames(Dat, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "Obs "),colnames(Dat, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "Sample "))
    ################ Visual Comparison via Box Plots ################
    boxplot(Dat)
    ################ Computation of Means and Variances of q Samples ################
    mx=apply(Dat,2,mean);mx
    vx=apply(Dat,2,var);vx
    ################ Computing Some Matrix Quantities ################
    Dn=diag(q,x=ni/vx);Dn
    Vn=diag(q,x=vx/(ni/n));Vn
    ################ Computing Vector and Matrix of 1's  and Associated Quantities################
    onq=matrix(rep(1,q),nrow=q)
    Iq=diag(q)
    Jq=onq%*%t(onq)
    Vn_1=solve(Vn)
    Wn=sum(ni/vx)
    Hn=Wn^(-1)*(Jq%*%Dn)
    Cn=Iq-Hn
    ################ Computing Unrestricted and Restricted Mean Vectors ################
    UE=as.matrix(mx);UE
    RE=Hn%*%UE;RE
```

Comment: write a function that returns UE, RE, and use `replicate`

Comment: Khashaa, I want to repeat the above code 1000 times and also wanted to store the UE and RE matrices of order (q*1) each for further manipulation. Thus there will be 1000 UE and RE matrices having different results in it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want something like this (I removed the boxplot and optimized the inner for to generate the values):

```
set.seed(20531)
NBoot=1000    

GenerateSamples <- function (){
  ################ Setting up various quantities ################
  alpha=0.05
  #c=0.5
  q=4
  ni=100
  n=q*ni;n
  ################ Setting Population Means and Standard Deviations ################
  mu0=c(5,5,5,5)
  sigma=c(1,1.5,2,2.5)
  ################ Creating Empty Matrix ################
  Dat=matrix(data=NA,nrow=ni,ncol=q)
  ################ Setting Up Loops ################
  for(j in 1:q){
    Dat[,j]<- rnorm(ni,mu0[j],sigma[j])
  }

  ################ Giving Names to Rows and Columns of DATA Matrix ################
  dimnames(Dat) <- list(rownames(Dat, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "Obs "),colnames(Dat, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "Sample "))
  ################ Visual Comparison via Box Plots ################
  #boxplot(Dat)
  ################ Computation of Means and Variances of q Samples ################
  mx=apply(Dat,2,mean)
  vx=apply(Dat,2,var)
  ################ Computing Some Matrix Quantities ################
  Dn=diag(q,x=ni/vx)
  Vn=diag(q,x=vx/(ni/n))
  ################ Computing Vector and Matrix of 1's  and Associated Quantities################
  onq=matrix(rep(1,q),nrow=q)
  Iq=diag(q)
  Jq=onq%*%t(onq)
  Vn_1=solve(Vn)
  Wn=sum(ni/vx)
  Hn=Wn^(-1)*(Jq%*%Dn)
  Cn=Iq-Hn
  ################ Computing Unrestricted and Restricted Mean Vectors ################
  UE=as.matrix(mx)
  RE=Hn%*%UE

  return (list(UE, RE))
}

UEs <- array(NA, 1000)
REs <- array(NA, 1000)
for (i in 1:NBoot){
   my_result <- GenerateSamples()
   UEs[i] <- my_result[1]
   REs[i] <- my_result[2]
}
```

Comment: mucio, Your code is ok as it gives UEs and REs but I cant apply any function like addition or subtraction to UEs and REs. Not only I want to store UEs and REs but I also want them to be ready for any mathematical operation.